# Apache rewrite folders in url as variables (like codeigniter)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite my URL's the following way using my .htaccess:

```
 http://localhost/admin/variable1/variable2/variable3/ (etc)
```

to:

```
 <?php
 $var1 = $_GET['variable1'];
 $var2 = $_GET['variable2'];
 $var3 = $_GET['variable3'];
 ?>
```

Also, it should work with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and more variables. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to have them as $_GET? You can use a general controller (redirecting all the requests pointing somewhere in http://localhost/admin/ to the same file) and explode the path with `/`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that: firstly create an **.htaccess** file, "assuming you're using apache".

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And PHP code will be something like that:

```
<?php

    $route = isset($_GET["r"]) ? $_GET["r"] : "/";
    var_dump($route, explode("/", $route));
```

And then, when you access the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/example/a/b/c/d/e/f
```

The output:

```
string 'a/b/c/d/e/f' (length=11)
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
  3 => string 'd' (length=1)
  4 => string 'e' (length=1)
  5 => string 'f' (length=1)
```